# IBOutlets getting nil when dismissing viewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, null, iboutlet

I have a ViewController from which I go to next ViewContoller. Now when I come back from second viewController using this code

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

My IB outlets are nil I do not know why

[image]

And I am getting this error `"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"`
    when I tru to access on one of my outlets like below

```
progress.setupPoint("10")
```

The error does  not occur when I come first time on this screen but only occures when I come back from next ViewController. Please help and guide. Thanks

> Update

Here are my IBOutlets. I change one of them from weak to strong

[image]

Comment: Show the code where your outlets are defined. It should be something like 
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

Comment: @Andrej please check update

Comment: Where do you set those outlets? Are you setting them inside your view controller class? Could it be that you've put your outlets outside your view controller and making them global. And later in your next view controller you could be setting them to a new view objects. But later when dismissing the second view controller you could get nil for those outlets. Could that be the case?

Comment: How are you presenting the first controller? How do you present the second controller?